# Replacing an attribute by use of attr function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <div>
     <a id="_a-link" href=""><img src="/local/img/image1.png" alt=""/></a>
 </div>
```

For that image link, I try the following jquery code to change its image source attribute into

```
 <div>
     <a id="_a-link" href=""><img src="/local/img/image2.png" alt=""/></a>
 </div>


$('#_a-link img').attr('src','');
$('#_a-link img').attr('src','/local/img/image2.png');
```

However the image displayed after all still is the same; it is image1.png not image2.png;

Comment: You have spelt src wrong in your jquery.

Comment: Hmm. Did you edit the question to remove the typo? Also I noticed below you said it still isn't fixed. It would be helpful if you could create a http://jsfiddle.net to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$('#_a-link img').attr('src','');
$('#_a-link img').attr({'src':'/local/img/image2.png', 'alt': ''});
```

Also you're doing it wrong with selectors. AFAIK, "#ID TAGNAME" selectors work pretty long. They will get all the img's and then will walk upstairs the DOM for each one to find some node with ID. You better add some class to needed images or if it's expected to be single use image id.

So the best optimized way is:

```
<a whatever here><img src="#" class="imgClass" /></a>
$(".imgClass");
```

Comment: You are missing a closing curly bracket in your first snippet. :)

Comment: thank you, this image actually lies in a slideshow and I applied what you hinted me but still can't make it work, the image doesn't change

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors? What browser are you using? If you're in Chrome, hit F12 and go to 'console'.

Comment: The code works - see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3prP/. If you're having problems, they're being caused by something else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted uses `scr`; it should be `src`:

```
 <div><a id="_a-link" href=""><img src="/local/img/image2.png" alt=""/></a>
 </div>

$('#_a-link img').attr('src','/local/img/image2.png');
```

You shouldn't need to blank it first, and the `alt` should be a separate invokation (if you need to change that too).

EDIT (based on comments below):

Here's a jsFiddle that uses this code: http://jsfiddle.net/h4tf6/

As you can see, it works just fine. If you have problems, there's most likely an error elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$('#_a-link img').attr("src").replace("/local/img/image1.png", "/local/img/image2.png");
```